# .NET 6.0 vs .NET Framework Number Rounding

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, floating-point, .net-6.0

As I was migrating a complex .NET Framework project to .NET 6.0, I noticed different results under some circumstances. I was able to trace down the issue to a basic inequality involving floats and a double. It can be represented by this one line of code:

```
Console.WriteLine(0.375F < 0.15F + 0.1F + 0.125);
```

.NET Framework returns `True` while .NET 6.0 returns `False`.

Unfortunately, this logic occurs thousands of times in the project and it will be a massive task to track and fix all instances. Any ideas as to how I can ensure the same behavior in .NET 6.0 as in .NET Framework?

Comment: FYI, if the project depended on these comparisons in the first place, it may be broken, as the author was apparently unaware of the rounding issues, and the comparisons of numbers very close to each other is effectively random, more a property of the happenstance roundings accumulated in a sequence of calculations than the relative relationship of the ideal results that would have been obtained with perfect real-number arithmetic. Ensuring the same behavior in new software might give you consistency with old results, but you should be aware it may be solidifying bugs.

Comment: Thanks @EricPostpischil for your comment. I would say that the author was not too worried about the cases where both sides of the inequality were so close and was happy for it to be true or false for the purposes of the software. However, the issue now is backwards compatibility for existing jobs. When users will open an old job in the new software, different results will be obtained. I might have to accept that if no way can be found. But it's not ideal...

Comment: SQL also gave same result as NET 6.0. So .NET Framework is wrong. If you want to return true in NET 6.0, can change < to <=